# Saving POST binary data with ADODB.Stream

Tags: asp-classic, ado

Another website sends me data with the POST method.

I would like to take this data and insert it into the database.

After some research online, I concluded that ADODB.Stream should do the job for me.

I dont have problem with getting the binary data with `Request.TotalBytes`.
With the following code, I am not receiving an error but it does not save the data either. So I must be doing something wrong with the ADODB Stream.

```
    tot_bytes = Request.TotalBytes

    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    BinaryStream.Mode = 3
    BinaryStream.Type = 1
    BinaryStream.Open       
    gBinaryData = BinaryStream.Write(tot_bytes) 
    BinaryStream.Close
    Set BinaryStream = Nothing

    SQL = "INSERT INTO STATUSES (StatusMessage, StatusDateEntered) VALUES ('"& gBinaryData &"', '"& FormatDateMySQL(NOW) &"')"                                  
    Set objAddC = objConn.execute(SQL)
```

.

```
Following a successful subscription, Facebook will proceed to call your endpoint every time that there are changes (to the chosen fields or connections). For each update, it will make an HTTP POST request.

The request will have content type of application/json and the body will comprise a JSON-encoded string containing one or more changes.

Note for PHP developers: In PHP, to get the encoded data you would use the following code:

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($data);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [**Write**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675017%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method does not return anything, in fact it's just a sub-routine. And Request.TotalBytes is just length of request in bytes. When you need to read request data as array of bytes, you should use Request.BinaryRead(length of bytes). Therefore, in Stream object, you need to read all of bytes using [**Read**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method after the writing bytes and setting position to the start.

However, it seems not neccessary in this case if you have to store the data as binary.
I assume that you need the data as text, most likely it's json string. So, you should convert data to string from bytes.

Note that, you need to handle an exception about total bytes. If the Request does not contain anything, `Request.TotalBytes` equals to zero and since `Request.BinaryRead` expects a number bigger than zero and less than or equal to total bytes an error occurs.

```vb
Dim tot_bytes, postData
    tot_bytes = Request.TotalBytes
If tot_bytes > 0 Then
    With Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        .Charset = "utf-8" 'specify the request encoding
        .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary, a binary stream
        .Open
        .Write Request.BinaryRead(tot_bytes) 'Write bytes
        .Position = 0 ' set position to the start
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText, stream type is text now
        postData = .ReadText 'read all text
        .Close
    End With
    With Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
        .Open "STATUSES", objConn , , 3
        .AddNew
        .Fields("StatusMessage").Value = postData
        .Fields("StatusDateEntered").Value = Now()
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
    Response.Write "data stored successfully"
Else
    Response.Write "no post data"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the fact that it is a very bad idea to directly insert your data into a database like this (possible sql injection), how do you post for form data? CLassic ASP can not handle binary data directly either. So this won't work at all.

So whatever you post, first you have to make sure that you post with form `enctype="multiform/data"`.
To get the data into a object try this instead:

```
byteArray = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)
```

BUt to handle it, store to database, or save to a file, you need a component, e.g. http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/upload.asp or try check this article (special when you upload more thatn just one file): http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19297/Pure-ASP-File-Upload.htm.

EDIT:
Antonin Fuller has also made a sample ASP code without using his DLL.
Try this, too:

```
Private Function RSBinaryToString(xBinary)
'Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
'RSBinaryToString converts binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY Or MultiByte string)
'to a string (BSTR) using ADO recordset

Dim Binary
'MultiByte data must be converted To VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY first.
If vartype(xBinary)=8 Then Binary = MultiByteToBinary(xBinary) Else Binary = xBinary

Dim RS, LBinary
Const adLongVarChar = 201
Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
LBinary = LenB(Binary)

If LBinary>0 Then
    RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarChar, LBinary
    RS.Open
    RS.AddNew
    RS("mBinary").AppendChunk Binary 
    RS.Update
    RSBinaryToString = RS("mBinary")
Else  
    RSBinaryToString = ""
End If
End Function
```

See more here: http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_binarytostring/

Finally you should get the stream, convert it, and work with it.

Comment: I dont have control on the POST side. Facebook makes a POST request when there is an update with my app. And they dont send it in a form, they send it. Just updated my original post, look at what they say.

Comment: Why you want to handle binary data then? They do send a JSON hash. So it is just "text". You need to find outif the form is multiform/data (which can't be accessed by classic ASP without extra components like the one I posted) or normal form. THen check the POST content and fetch the data.

Comment: But they dont send it in a form. I cannot receive the data with Request.Form because they dont mention about it at all. For php users they suggest, `$data = file_get_contents("php://input");` to receive the data.

Comment: Well try the code line from my answer and response.write the `byteArray` and see what is in there. If it is the JSON text, then it should work.

Comment: I tried that before. It doesnt display anything. but `response.write Request.TotalBytes` displays a value.

Comment: Tried `Response.BinaryWrite`?